# Heroku flask + socket.io 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: flask, heroku, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hello im trying to deploy my flask app on heroku. Im using flask_socketio module and socket.io in version 4.5(i didn't know how to initialize in 2.3.x version - io())

Here's my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, session, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
#secret key etc...
...
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_msg(msg):
    socketio.send('Syncing...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Here's my javascript:

```
...

export const socket = io();
socket.connect('https://proman-code-cool.herokuapp.com/');

function init() {

    ...

    //live sync
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        boardsManager.reloadBoards(userId);
    });
}

init();
```

And what i want is to make real-time sync to other users after adding something. And this is working locally but on heroku ive got all the time similar errors to:

[image: 400 BAD request]

When i've changed my Procfile to `web: gunicorn -k eventlet main:app` and with installed eventlet 0.30.2 i've got errors like `class uri 'eventlet' invalid or not found`. I can't find anywhere solution for that.

Comment: Have you googled your error message? First hit seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589138/error-class-uri-eventlet-invalid-or-not-found

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Of course i did, and that error i get when i downgrade that eventlet package and app is crashing. There's no answer for that problem. I think that problem can be newer version of socket.io but there's no instruction how to apply old one(2.4.x) from cdn. I don't want to use node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventlet==0.30.2` in requirements.txt and `python-3.8.13` in runtime.txt did the job!
Procfile: `web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 main:app`